# How to trigger a build from another build pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build-pipeline

I have two build pipeline for two different projects.One is for building the actual project and another build pipeline for test automation. I want to automatically trigger the build pipeline of test automation once the actual project build succeed.

does there any possible way can i add one more task down to the actual build to trigger the test automation build, or suggest a possible way for the same.

[image]

Answers are much appreciable!!

Comment: 1) May be a slightly different question. Why can't you add a task to directly invoke the tests in the build pipeline itself at the end. 2) Moreover, Did you try checking the option `triggers` ?

Comment: Very sorry, I am pretty new to azure devops could explain how its really done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Build Completion" trigger in your second pipeline:

[image]

Additionally, you can add PowerShell script to queue another build from the parent build. Example:

```
$user = ""
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI"
$teamProject = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
$buildBodyTemplate = "{`"definition`": {`"id`": <build_id>}}"

$restApiQueueBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"

function InvokePostRequest ($PostUrl, $body)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body
}

function RunBuild($buildId)
{
    $buildBody = $buildBodyTemplate.Replace("<build_id>", $buildId)            
    Write-Host $buildBody
    
    $buildresponse = InvokePostRequest $restApiQueueBuild $buildBody
    Write-Host $buildresponse
}

RunBuild SECOND_BUILD_ID
```

Update `SECOND_BUILD_ID` to ID of your build definition with tests. Additionally, add access to the security token in the parent build:

[image]